# Mysql server has gone away - During mysqldump

Tags: mysql, dump

Every evening (8.00pm PST) i make a global backup of my production database (innoDB engine).

Heres the mysqldump command :

```
mysqldump -u$MYSQLUSER -p$MYSQLPWD -h$MYSQLHOST -Q -c -C --add-drop-table --add-locks --quick --lock-tables surveys > $MYSQLBACKUPDIR/surveys.$NOW.sql;
```

Backup takes approximately 45 minutes and generates a 480 MB sql file.
During this backup some users of my website can encounter errors (500)

Here's what i find in my apache error log :

```
[Sun Dec 10 20:32:58.028079 2017] [:error] [pid 10921] DBD::mysql::db commit failed: MySQL server has gone away at /var/www/---.pl line 17.\n
```

This is what i tried in order to solve this issue:

- Raise values in mySQL configuration (wait_timeout, max_allowed_packet)
- Cleaning my database, removed 1/5 of old records (backup file from 600MB to 480)

But without success :(

Comment: Generally, when I get the `MySQL server has gone away` error, is when there is an open connection to the database with none activity for some sort of time. Is there any chance of your backup blocking (stopping and wating for another process) at some point?

Answer (score 0):

It could be down to locking tables, but I may be wrong. Instead of your parameter `--lock-tables`, you could use:
`--single-transaction --lock-tables=false`. This way your dump will be consistent but will not lock tables for so long.
Also - if you can, try to use innobackupex. But backing up and restoring single database is much more complicated than with mysqldump. Here some details: **https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtrabackup/10131-backing-up-and-restoring-a-single-database**

Comment: Thank you! Isn't the lock-tables=false facultative? In the doc i can read "The --single-transaction option and the --lock-tables option are mutually exclusive because LOCK TABLES causes any pending transactions to be committed implicitly."

Comment: You are right, but here I set lock-tables=false - means "do not lock tables", which actually is ensured by single-transaction. I put it there to make me double sure ;)

Comment: Jarek, no SQL error this night, seems it worked :)
Thank you for your advice